# Apache APC and httpd reload

Tags: php, apache, apc

Our website has 5 webheads (redhat) each with a very basic apc.ini.

```
extension=apc.so 
apc.stat=0 
apc.shm_size=96m
```

We do logrotations for apache at 4am daily. **Sometimes** after a logrotate/httpd reload.. PHP constants stored in a yaml file which is cached by APC become unreadable.  This does not happen every day.. it happens randomly on a random web server (1-5). An apache restart fixes the issue and the webserver can read the PHP constants from the .yaml file again.

When we deploy code we do an httpd graceful and never see this issue.  I'm under the impression that restarts/gracefuls will clear the APC cache but httpd reloads will not? We have switched our logrotates to use graceful over rotate for now but would like further insight if anyone has run into this issue as well. (Keep in mind it is not every single constant but seemingly random ones from the file).

To recap: after a logrotate a webserver may not be able to read a PHP constant from an APC cached yaml file any longer until a httpd restart/graceful has been executed.

```
APC version = 3.1.13 
PHP = 5.4.7 
Apache = 2.2.3
```

Comment: "a webserver may not be able to read a PHP constant from an APC cached yaml file" --- why don't you repopulate the cache in case if it was dropped (for any reason)?

Comment: Doing an apache restart will repopulate the cache. We do a httpd graceful when this happens and this DOES resolve the issue. I guess what I'm really asking is why does this happen on the logrates httpd reload?

Comment: It's not clear what "this" happens. If some cache entry disappears - it's fine for cache.